# admin-username error of proxy

Tags: mysql, mysql-proxy

I tried to install proxy on development machine and I got the following error.

```
/etc/init.d/mysql-proxyd start
Starting mysql-proxy: 2011-02-26 15:51:45: (critical) admin-plugin.c:569: --admin-username needs to be set
2011-02-26 15:51:45: (critical) mainloop.c:267: applying config of plugin admin failed
2011-02-26 15:51:45: (critical) mysql-proxy-cli.c:596: Failure from chassis_mainloop. Shutting down.
[  OK  ]
```

Since this is only a test machine, I do not want the security feature of proxy. How do I avoid the above error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either upgrade your version of mysql-proxy to 0.8.2 or greater or explicitly specify that you don't need the admin plugin by using `mysql-proxy --plugins=proxy`

Answer (score 2):

```
[mysql-proxy]
daemon = true
user = mysql
proxy-skip-profiling = true
keepalive = true
max-open-files = 2048
event-threads = 50
pid-file = /var/run/mysql-proxy.pid
log-file = /var/log/mysql-proxy.log
log-level = debug
admin-address=:4401
admin-username=1 
admin-password=1 
admin-lua-script=/usr/local/lib/mysql-proxy/lua/admin.lua
proxy-address = 0.0.0.0:3307
proxy-backend-addresses = 192.168.2.1:3306
proxy-read-only-backend-addresses=192.168.6.2:3306, 192.168.6.1:3306
proxy-lua-script=/usr/lib/mysql-proxy/lua/proxy/balance.lua
```